# What replaces the now removed Kotest arrow matcher shouldBeSome function variant?

Tags: kotest

In prior versions of kotest-assertions-arrow, it was possible to write:

```
someOption.shouldBeSome { 
  it.foo shouldBe "x"
  it.bar shouldBe "y"
}
```

I just upgraded to v1.2.1 and this variant has been removed. Only the literal value variant remains

```
someOption.shouldBeSome(t: T)
```

What replaces the older style?

Answer (score 2):

One possible answer is

```
someOption.shouldBeSome().let {
  it.foo shouldBe "x"
  it.bar shouldBe "y"
}
```